# update rows after select in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a query in a table, and then the select, i need to update a column in the same table.

THE TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTE
(
    RUT           VARCHAR2(14), 
    FONO1   VARCHAR(20),
    FONO2   VARCHAR(20),
    FONO3   VARCHAR(20),
    FONO4   VARCHAR(20),
    FONO5   VARCHAR(20),
    FONO6   VARCHAR(20),
    FLAG    CHAR(1)
)
;

CREATE TABLE TEMPORAL
    (
        RUT           VARCHAR2(14), 
        FONO1   VARCHAR(20),
        FONO2   VARCHAR(20),
        FONO3   VARCHAR(20),
        FONO4   VARCHAR(20),
        FONO5   VARCHAR(20),
        FONO6   VARCHAR(20),
        FLAG    CHAR(1)
    )
    ;
```

THE QUERY

```
SELECT CL.* FROM CLIENTE CL
INNER JOIN TEMPORAL TM
ON CL.RUT = TM.RUT;
WHERE CL.FLAG = 'N';
```

Here I need to update the column "FLAG" with 'Y' just in the rows of the select.

Comment: What do you mean by "update" - an actual update in the base table (an `UPDATE` or perhaps `MERGE` statement)? Or just in the output of the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to update a column in the same table and
>
> ...
>
> Here I need to update the column "FLAG" with 'Y'

I assume you mean table `CLIENTE`. You can use any of these queries.

Using `MERGE INTO`:

```
MERGE INTO CLIENTE m
USING 
(
    SELECT CL.RUT, CL.FLAG FROM CLIENTE CL
    INNER JOIN TEMPORAL TM
    ON CL.RUT = TM.RUT
    WHERE CL.FLAG = 'Y'
) c ON ( m.RUT = c.RUT ) 
WHEN matched then UPDATE SET m.FLAG = 'N';
```

Using `EXISTS`:

```
UPDATE cliente CL
SET    CL.flag = 'Y'
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   temporal TM
               WHERE  CL.rut = TM.rut
                      AND CL.flag = 'N');
```